# How to display data from GAS and update automatically for each cells?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to display data from GAS and automatically for each cells in spreadsheet.
I tried "appendRow", but it was error(over 2000000 cells).
If I can "appendRow", plz tell me.

Now, I try other way, but I can't.

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var n=1; n <= 9; n++) {
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=1");
    var obj = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());  
    obj["news"][n]["id"];
    obj["news"][n]["url"];
    obj["news"][n]["image"];

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10fIsep_NJPtpKUQZrV6XAgrwhtua7zEr8rowdqalWJM");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("gas-json");

    var array = [obj["news"][n]["id"], obj["news"][n]["url"], obj["news"][n]["image"]];
    var id = obj["news"][n]["id"]
    var url = obj["news"][n]["url"]
    var image = obj["news"][n]["image"]

    var cell = sheet.getRange("A2:A10");
        cell.setValue(id);

  }
};
```

From line12, I'm in trouble because the spreadsheet displays like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN9bB.png).

I want to do like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG9on.png).
And I want to update automatically after last row.
So I tried "appendRow" in other code, but I can't.

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var n=1; n <= 9; n++) {

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.ookami.me/v1/news/public?sport_id=1");

    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    json["news"][4,n]["id"]); 
    json["news"][7,n]["url"]);
    json["news"][1,n]["image"]);

    var array = [json["news"][4,n]["id"]), json["news"][7,n]["url"]), json["news"][1,n]["image"])];

    sheet.appendRow(array)

  }
}
```

Plz tell me answer....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your first code snippet works correct

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("A2:A10");
        cell.setValue(id);
```

Could you please first of all add the following code in order to see if this what you expect?

```
var cellB = sheet.getRange("B2:B10");
            cell.setValue(url);
var cellC = sheet.getRange("C2:C10");
            cell.setValue(image);
```